# AFRAME.registerGeometry Doc Example Throwing Errors

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

The example code at the end of the docs under "Register A Custom Geometry":
https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/geometry.html#register-a-custom-geometry
throws a "core:schema:warn" error.

Is anyone successfully registering custom geometries in A-Frame or is this something that's currently broken A-Frame itself?

Comment: Are you registering the geometry *before* it's used in `<a-scene>`? All the geometries in A-Frame use this API.

Comment: Hey Kevin! That is the problem, but I haven't found a perfect solution because now I use two js files. One in the header to registerGeometry and registerComponents, then one in the footer to add additional js logic. It wont work to have all the code in the header js file. I'm looking through your examples on github to see if I can identify the problem.

Comment: Move the necessary code in the footer to the header? Or I recommend encapsulating code within components such that code is sure to be executed once everything is set up and initialized and to get references to the scene element.